# Detect PnPEntity insertion

Tags: .net, wmi

I'm using a ManagementEventWatcher in C# to monitor WMI PnPEntity events.  My query is this:
"SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'"

When I plug in a specific device that has already been inserted into the PC the event is raised and everything is fine.  However, if I insert a new piece of hardware of the same type (ie. PID and VID are the same, but a new DeviceID) the event is raised immediately, but the ConfigManagerErrorCode == 1 ("Device is not configured correctly").

The driver will then be installed for the device and if I remove the device and reinsert, everything is fine.

How do I detect when the driver has finished installing?  Is there a better event to watch besides __InstanceCreationEvent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [__InstanceModificationEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394651%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead and throw out the first ones when configuring a new device?

if you are looking at a specific device like a NIC or Hard Drive you may want to look for events on a different class since the one you are looking at is rather broad.

There are also some other P/Invoke Options [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/HwDetect.aspx)(have to convert the c++ to c#)